# Calculate the memory occupied by a SQLite database theoretically

Tags: python, sqlite, memory

I have a SQLite table with 370 tables, each table has 14 days including 4am to 8pm data in minutes which constitute a row. Also, each row has 6 fields. When I save my file I get 100KB, but when I calculate it, it becomes almost 1GB (considering each cell is 40 bytes). What am I missing:

**My calculation:**

```
days = 14
# 8pm - 4am 
hrs = 20-4
m = hrs*60
print(m)
rows = days*m
print(rows)
fields = 6
cells = rows*fields
print(cells)
tables = 370
cells = tables*cells
bs = cells*40
print(bs)

960
13440
80640
1193472000
```

Comment: Are you sure each cell use 40 bytes ? the file format is decribed here : [Record Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#record_format), e.g. a NULL, 0 or 1 uses only 1 byte

Comment: @bwt: I am not sure. I just defined SQLite with some fields. Am I missing something?

Comment: the size depends on the actual content

Comment: @bwt: here is the content: "2022-02-07 04:01:00", "172.3900", "172.3900", "172.1600", "172.3900", "2886.0".